# What does "think again!" mean as an exclamation?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm reading a children's book ([this one](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Loving_Spirit_Dreams/YIKX8zORV-wC?hl=it&gbpv=1&dq=%22ellie%20carrington%20leant%20against%22&pg=PT9&printsec=frontcover)) and I found this expression in a dialogue. The dictionaries don't help me much to understand the meaning, which I suppose is ironic, but I'm not sure.

Here's the context.
A boy and a girl are training a pony:

‘He needs to go slower, I think!’ Ellie called. ‘It says here [on a horse-training manual]: “the horse should settle into a steady trot”. Can you slow Solo down while keeping him going round the outside?’
‘I think so.’ Joe moved so he was level with the pony’s neck. Solo instantly bounced to a stop. With a snort, he turned and raced in the other direction at an even faster canter than before.
Ellie giggled. ‘Think again!’

Is the meaning of the exclamation ironic? Can someone formulate the sentence differently to help me understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you tell someone to 'think again', you mean that you consider they have given the wrong answer to a question and they should think about that question again.

Joe says he *thinks* he can slow the pony down, but it turns out that he can't.

Comment: So, the meaning of the sentence is more like "try again" or "You should not act like this"?

Comment: No, the meaning is "You were wrong in thinking you could slow him down; you must find another answer to my question!"